# Why is my GCP managed Cert not working with kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I have the following that seems to work...

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: thanos-static
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: test-app
      port:
        number: 8000
```

I am trying to add ssl so I change to the following...

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
  namespace: test
spec:
  domains:
    - me.mine.co
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: thanos-static
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: test-app
      port:
        number: 8000
```

I set everything up on the DNS side and can access `http` but when I try to hit `https` I get...

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to me.mine.co. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Worked after a while. It apparently needed time to propagate.